# Looking for Journey Builder Best Practice for Engagement on Multiple Emails

Tags: journeybuilder, marketing-cloud

Using Journey Builder In the Scenario of

- Send email day 1,
- wait 48 hours,
- re-send to those who have not opened
- wait 48 more hours
- resend to those who have not opened

I see a handful of Gaps with JB and engagement splits. How are people handling them today?

Issue #1 - Engagement Split only looks at 1 email (I assume we focus on the most recent), but what about that anomaly case of users who open the first email and not the resend

Issue #2 - can't look for a click or an open, need to have back-to-back engagement Splits to treat those behaviors differently.  Correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right direction. When you use engagement split it can able to look only one email. You need to add another engagement split to look for another email. Similarly if you want to look both open and click you would need to have another engagement split.

However, if you are someone who like SQL query then you can follow the below approach:

- Add 2 attribute in the journey data extension named 'opened' and
  'clicked'.
- Create a different automation and schedule it hourly with the below
  SQL query, so that it populates the value in the attributes.

Query to find if they have opened, I have mentioned it as 2 days since you have 48 hours as wait interval.

```
SELECT a.SubscriberKey,
Opened = 1
FROM [myDE] a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT TOP 1 o.SubscriberKey from [_Open] o
  WHERE o.SubscriberKey = a.SubscriberKey
  AND o.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = {{"Interaction ID"}}
  AND o.EventDate > (CAST(GETDATE() - 2 as Date))
)
```

Query to find if they have clicked.

```
SELECT a.SubscriberKey,
Clicked = 1
FROM [myDE] a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT TOP 1 o.SubscriberKey from [_Click] o
  WHERE o.SubscriberKey = a.SubscriberKey
  AND o.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = {{"Interaction ID"}}
  AND o.EventDate > (CAST(GETDATE() - 2 as Date))
)
```

Post this you can just add a decision split based on the opened on clicked attribute. You don't have to handle it in engagement split.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thank you Naveen - glad to see i wasn't missing anything. I like your idea.  My original thought was to use SQL to find the anomaly user case customers and inject them into the same or new journey.  Without much thought, both solutions will work and have pros and cons that need to be weighed.  - As an FYI my driving decision maker is usability/maintenance for the team I hand this off to.

Comment: Thanks again @naveen

Comment: trying to tag you and it wont let me lol

Comment: Lol @Patrick, you are welcome !